# addSubview and autosizing

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsview, nswindow, autosize

**How does one add views to a window, so that the views are resized to fit within the window frame?**

## The problem

I'm making a sheet window containing 2 views, where only one of them is visible at a time,
so it's important that the views have the same size as the window. My problem is that either
view0 fits correctly and view1 doesn't or the other way around. I can't figure out how to
give them the same size as the window.

## Possible solution

I could just make sure that both views have precisely the same size within Interface Builder, then it would work. However I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically.

---

### Screenshot of view0

Below you can see the autoresizing problem in the top and the right side, where the view is somehow clipped.

[image: view0]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm5.static.flickr.com/4002/4550783724_7f59889543_o.png))</sub>

---

### Screenshot of view1

This view is resized correctly.

[image: view1]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm5.static.flickr.com/4052/4550783774_bd018e7ec8_o.png))</sub>

---

### Here is my code

Can the views be resized before adding them to the window. Or is it better to do as I do now where the views are added one by one while changing the window frame. How do you do it?

```
NSView* view0 = /* a view made with IB */;
NSView* view1 = /* another view made with IB */;
NSWindow* window = [self window];

NSRect window_frame = [window frame];

NSView* cv = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:window_frame] autorelease];
[window setContentView:cv];
[cv setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

// add subview so it fits within the contentview frame
{
    NSView* v = view0;
    [v setHidden:YES];
    [v setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
    [cv addSubview:v];
    [v setFrameOrigin:NSZeroPoint];
    [window setFrame:[v frame] display:NO];
    [v setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
}

// add subview so it fits within the contentview frame
{
    NSView* v = view1;
    [v setHidden:YES];
    [v setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
    [cv addSubview:v];
    [v setFrameOrigin:NSZeroPoint];
    [window setFrame:[v frame] display:NO];
    [v setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
}

// restore original window frame
[window setFrame:window_frame display:YES];

[view0 setHidden:NO];
[view1 setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solved!** I have [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967625/nsviews-autoresizing-behavior/1002891#1002891) here on stackoverflow.

Would be nice if this code could be made shorter though.

```
NSView* view0 = /* a view made with IB */;
NSView* view1 = /* another view made with IB */;
NSWindow* window = [self window];

NSRect window_frame = [window frame];

NSView* cv = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:window_frame] autorelease];
[window setContentView:cv];
[cv setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

// add subview so it fits within the contentview frame
{
    NSView* v = view0;
    NSRect vframe = [v frame];
    [v setHidden:YES];
    [v setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

    NSView* tmp_superview = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:vframe] autorelease];
    [tmp_superview addSubview:v];
    [tmp_superview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [tmp_superview setFrame:window_frame];

    [v removeFromSuperview];
       [cv addSubview:v];
}

// add subview so it fits within the contentview frame
{
    NSView* v = view1;
    NSRect vframe = [v frame];
    [v setHidden:YES];
    [v setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

    NSView* tmp_superview = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:vframe] autorelease];
    [tmp_superview addSubview:v];
    [tmp_superview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [tmp_superview setFrame:window_frame];

    [v removeFromSuperview];
    [cv addSubview:v];
}

[view0 setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score -1):

The window can not know which view you want to autosize.So you must set AutoresizezingMask

[view setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];