# NSTabView inside NSSplitView and autosizing mask - causing core plot graphs to not resize

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-plot

Friends,

I have a NSSplitView (top to bottom and two panes). Inside second pane i have a tab view with four tab items. Each tab item view is coreplot hosting view. Now issue i am facing is that core plot graph does not resize when split view size changes. Initially i though it might be core-plot bug and to verify it i created a demo project with same view hierarchy and core-plot but it works fine as needed.

After comparing one by one all views of my project and demo project i found that autosizing mask in demo project of NSTabView (that is under split view) is set to resize width and height where as in my project it is not. Also autosizing mask view is disabled so i can't even configured it.

As i have subclassed tab view so thought having below in tabview subclass will work but it is not.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib{


[self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[self setAutoresizingMask: (NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];

}
```

Refer the screen shot:[image: screen shot with differences in autosize properties]

Please help.

Thanks,
MP.

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Does your app use auto layout?

Comment: No it is not using auto layout.

Comment: There are some helpful hints on the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967625/nsviews-autoresizing-behavior).